# How to Open Drawer On OnPress from Stack.Screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer

I am trying to open drawer from homeScreen. drawer is opening when I swipe right but. I want to open Draer onPress of menu Icon. But Its not working. I used openDrawer, toggleDrawer but nothing work.

here is my code

```
function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="homeScreen">
      <Drawer.Screen name="homeSreen" component={homeScreen} 
      
      options={{
        headerLeft: () => <Icon
            name="menu"
            size={25}
            color="#D4AF37"
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
  }} 
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="splashScreen" component={splashScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={loginScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="homeScreen" component={MyDrawer}  />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

in react-navigation V5

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Comment: no its not working I think I done somthing wrong in navigation

Comment: which version of Navigation you are using?

Comment: 5 version i am usin 5

Comment: here is complete documentation
https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding navigation in function MyDrawer()

like this `function MyDrawer({navigation}) {...}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` to open drawer

```
                 <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
                    }}>
                    <Icon name="bars" size={21} color="rgb(112, 112, 112)" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
```